# bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot showing: An error occurred while attempting to delete the specified data element. Element not found

Tags: dual-boot, rstudio, rst

I was dual booting my Dell Inspiron laptop and landed on an intel RST problem. I followed the steps as shown on this link- https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347/94

But, in the "bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot" step, I'm getting an error: "An error occurred while attempting to delete the specified data element. Element not found." I tried all three bcdedit codes as shown in the tutorial. How should I proceed?

Comment: Bumped on exactly the same problem, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while trying to boot Windows with AHCI enabled. (This was needed to  dual boot Ubuntu with Windows that was using Intel RST.)

After trying those commands multiple times and searching for solutions, figured that even though it showed an error, it probably ran just fine.
Was able to verify this by closing the command prompt and letting the system boot to Windows 11, which it did successfully and the SATA controller was changed to AHCI.